# Cannot remove a div in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove a div in Javascript but 'its not working. I get no error in my console yet the function does get called.

I don't understand what I have done wrong, so I'm hoping someone can explain. This is how it works:

```
function menu_load(type){
  document.getElementById(type).onclick = function(){ menu_unload(type); }
  var width = 100;
  var height = 100;
  var d = document.createElement('div');
  d.id = 'menu';
  d.className = 'menu';
  d.style.width = width + 'px';
  d.style.height = height + 'px';
  document.getElementById('G').appendChild(d);
}

function menu_unload(type){
  alert('test'); //this displays
  var div = document.getElementById("menu");
  div.parentNode.removeChild(div); // doesn't remove the div
  document.getElementById(type).onclick = menu_load(type);
}

window.onload = function(){
  menu_load('test');
}
```

Is there any mistake here that I have missed? I just can't work out the problem.

Comment: you say "the function" does get called.  Do you mean `menu_unload` or just `menu_load`?

Comment: both, it loads the div when I append and my alert displays for `menu_unload` with the `onclick`

Comment: put your `alert` call at the end of `menu_unload` and see if it still gets called

Comment: I created a jsfiddle with a smaller test case, and it works...  maybe it'll help.  http://jsfiddle.net/KcEKL/

Comment: It helps only if jQuery was what i used but i am using Javascript. @Igor will test it now!

Comment: @Igor alert works on the last line for menu_unload ! so all the lines get executed !

Comment: This works too http://jsfiddle.net/KcEKL/1/, jquery was just to trigger that function with the button, your function was still intact, and still worked

Comment: you're trying to attach a `click` listener to the element that just has been removed - http://jsfiddle.net/7cFtE/  note the commented out very last line

Comment: @ZoltanToth im adding a click to div id "test" not "menu"...=/  but that would give a console error and would still remove the div which is not occuring for me. let me check a second browser.

Comment: ah, sorry I think I was confused with my fiddles, please disregard.

Comment: @Dave - see Paul's comment to nnnnnn's answer.

Comment: You should definitely use jQuery. It's really great and does all things. </sarcasm>

Comment: I'm so glad you put </sarcasm> cos for a brief second I believed you were serious :P

Comment: Yep. If you go back about a week and a half you'll find @Tesserex's opening `<sarcasm>` tag in another question.

Comment: @nnnnnn I actually felt quite guilty / dirty for knowingly having unbalanced tags.

Comment: Everything i do is without libraries - i personally don't like them. I like the long way :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code works for me if I correct the following line:

```
document.getElementById(type).onclick = menu_load(type);
```

Which incorrectly calls `menu_load()` and tries to assign the result to `.onclick`. It should be like you did in the other function

```
document.getElementById(type).onclick = function() { menu_load(type); };
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MCZza/

<s>To be honest I don't know why this fixes it, since</s> your code wasn't actually a syntax error, *but because it called* `menu_load()` *it recreated the div just removed.* <s>and the `.removeChild()` line should happen first, but anyway...</s>

Comment: +1, but @ "I don't know why this fixes it", it is because calling `menu_load` is creating a new `<div>` which is exactly the same, so you can't tell the difference by eye.

Comment: Ah, thanks @PaulS. - I didn't think it through even though I said "[this] calls `menu_load()`". I'll update my answer.

Comment: @PaulS. - thank you, man, you nailed it. You should put it as an answer.

Comment: Ah so it was doing it but immediately re-creating it ?

Comment: @Igor as much as I like reputation I don't think a new answer is warranted as this one covers the solution adequately.

Comment: I'll upvote your comments @PaulS. thats better than no rep :)